# Disable first item of BottomNavigationMenu?

Tags: android, xml, navigation

I would like to disable the first item of a BottomNavigationMenu. I tried it this way:

```
  bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setEnabled(false);
```

I have used a style for disabled items. The style seems to work for all items except the first item. I also tried the set the item to a disabled state by editing the xml. But the button always looks the same way.

Here is my XML for styling the menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/secondaryColor" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:color="@color/secondaryColor" android:state_enabled="true"/>

<item android:color="#BEBEBE" android:state_enabled="false"/>

</selector>
```

And this is the menu:

```
   <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tab_items"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/tab_items"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_portfolio_view" />
```

The navigation is defined this way:

```
<menu
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_notifications_24"
    android:title="Item 1"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
    android:title="Item 2"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item3"
    android:enabled="true"

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_add_24"
    android:title="Item 3"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/additional_features"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_pending_24"
    android:title="Additional features"/>
</menu>
```

Do you have any idea why the first item cannot be changed (via code or XML)? It should be greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

it's because the first item in the menu is also "checked" at first.

in your "tab_items" file - you can remove the line :

```
<item android:color="@color/secondaryColor" android:state_checked="true"/>
```

and then the icon will be grey.